# Pixel MTP Drivers for Windows

Tags: windows, usb-drivers, google-pixel

Is there someplace I can download the Windows MTP drivers for the Pixel that is *not* Windows Update?

Plugging my Pixel into a Windows box results in the following:

[image: Device Manager]

Trying to update the driver fails:

[image: Could not find driver]

I have tried several different 3rd party cables after reading the supplied cable caused some people problems. I have tried rebooting my computer after some had said that fixed the issue. I have tried switching from File Transfer mode to Photo Transfer mode and back again. No difference.

I have also read that some people were able to manually select MTP Device from the list of available drivers in Windows Update. There is no such listing in my list.

Is this driver available anywhere other than Windows Update so I can just use the Have Disk install method? Can someone pull the `.inf` or `.sys` file off their system and post it some place? I can host it in Dropbox or Drive or someplace but I currently have no way to get it in the first place.